# Как написать запрос в JpaRepository, где в качестве параметра метода используется список?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Имеется приложение на `Hibernate`, `Spring Data Jpa`. В приложении есть некоторая сущность с полем **id**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entities_table")
public class Entity {
    
    @Id
    public Integer id;
}
```

У меня есть множество id: `Set<Integer> ids`. Я хочу передать это множество в параметры метода JpaRepository и вытащить сразу все сущности, id которых имеется в множестве. Я хочу сделать что-то такое:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface EntityDao extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.id IN :ids")
    Set<Entity> getAllById(Set<Integer> ids);
}
```

Как мне правильно составить запрос?

Comment: Скобок не хватает `WHERE p.id IN (:ids)`, а в остальном должно работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых есть вариант от `@Roman Konoval`:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface EntityDao extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.id IN (:ids)")
    Set<Entity> getAllById(Set<Integer> ids);
}
```

В данном случае надо просто обернуть `:ids` в скобки.

---

Имеется и второй вариант. Он основан на механизме `Spring Data JPA`, который распознаёт название метода в JpaRepository и автоматически составляет запрос. Например, вот это:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.id=:id")
Entity get(Integer id);
```

легко заменяется на это:

```
Entity getById(Integer id);
```

На самом деле вариантов использования этого механизма довольно много, их можно посмотреть вот [здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation). Конкретно в моём случае можно сделать вот так:

```
Set<Entity> findByIdIn(Set<Integer> ids);
```